# Issue with my voting system in C# asp.net MVC project. Idea is based on StackOverflow voting system

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a voting system on answers post just like StackOverflow. I am able to do `ajax` request and everything is stored perfectly as the desired way in the database. But I am facing an issue with my `View`. In my view, all the `answers`'s `Html` is rendered with one `for` loop. In this `Html` element, I am selecting `answer` by `div` class called `vote` with `jQuery` and doing my ajax call and updating my vote count. But the issue is when I am upvoting one answer, Instead of increasing only its vote count, it increases all the answers vote count at the same time.
I think the mistake in selecting all the `div` with the `vote` `class` name. But I am not able to find a way to select them separately to increase my `VoteCount` on the selected answers only.
Here is my `View` Code.

```
@model AskMe.Models.ViewModel.QuestionDetailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QuestionDetails";
}

<h1>Question Details: </h1>
<h3>@Model.question.Post.Title</h3>
@Html.Raw(Model.question.Post.Content)
<hr />
<h3>Answers:</h3>
<div id="paginationContainer">
    @foreach (var answer in Model.question.Answers)
    {
        <div class="card bg-light m-1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Answered by: @answer.Post.CreatedBy.UserName</h5>
                @Html.Raw(answer.Post.Content)
            </div>
            <div class="col vote">
                <div>
                    <button data-vote-id="@answer.Post.PostId" class="nav-link thumbs-up" href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="Count">
                    @(answer.Post.UpVotes.Count-answer.Post.DownVotes.Count)
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button data-vote-id="@answer.Post.PostId" class="nav-link thumbs-down" href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ActionLink("View Comments", "Index", "Comments", new { answerId = answer.PostId }, null) |
        </div>
    }
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h3>Contribute your answer: </h3>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AnswerContent, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerContent, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.question)
                <input type="submit" value="Contribute now" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval");

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode: "textareas",
            });
            $('#paginationContainer').buzinaPagination({
                itemsOnPage: 3,
                prevnext: true,
                prevText: "Previous",
                nextText: "Next"
            });

            $(".vote").on("click", ".thumbs-up", function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/votes/upvote/" + $(this).attr("data-vote-id"),
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        var countTxt = $(".Count").text();
                        console.log(countTxt);
                        var count = parseInt(countTxt);
                        $(".Count").text(count + 1);
                        console.log(count);
                    }
                })
            })

            $(".vote").on("click", ".thumbs-down", function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/votes/downvote/" + $(this).attr("data-vote-id"),
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        var countTxt = $(".Count").text();
                        console.log(countTxt);
                        var count = parseInt(countTxt);
                        $(".Count").text(count - 1);
                        console.log(count);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

and here is my `ViewModel`

```
public class QuestionDetailViewModel
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public virtual Question question { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Add your answer.")]
        public string AnswerContent { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        public int AnswerId { get; set; }

        public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It seems ok probably the problem is in the api code. You can check the network tab in the developer tools. See how many requests it makes per click.

Comment: It is making a single XHR request per click. It is sending different Id on different answers also.

Comment: So then it is your api implementation if messing things up. Please share the details of how you update your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @EugenePodskal to point out my mistake and show me the correct direction for the solution. Here is the solution for question.

```
$(".vote").on("click", ".thumbs-up", function () {
                var counter = $(this).closest(".vote").children(".Count");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/votes/upvote/" + $(this).attr("data-vote-id"),
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function () {
                        var countTxt = counter.text();
                        console.log(countTxt);
                        var count = parseInt(countTxt);
                         counter.text(count + 1);
                        console.log(count);
                    }
                })
            })
```

Thanks again @EUgenePodskal for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting and setting all `.Count` elements as far as I can see in

```
var countTxt = $(".Count").text();
...
$(".Count").text(count - 1);
```

While we should handle only those `.Count` elements that are related to the current answer.

It can be done with [ancestor](https://api.jquery.com/ancestor/) + [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) selector

```
var $count = $(this).ancestor(".vote").children(".Count")[0];
$.ajax({  
    url: "/api/votes/downvote/" + $(this).attr("data-vote-id"),
    method: "POST",
    success: function () {
        var countTxt = $count.text();
        ...
        $count.text(count - 1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I implemented your solution but it gives an error of `4:163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined` on line `var countTxt = $element.children(".Count")[0].text();`

Comment: @AbhijeetBrahmbhatt Fixed - `this` is on the same level as `.Count`, so `children()` won't work.

Comment: Still the same issue. But the good thing is now, the vote is changing as desired by refreshing the page and the count is not affecting other answer's vote count. Just instant change on count is not working due to that `4:163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined `

Comment: @AbhijeetBrahmbhatt Now it probably should work - I seem to be slightly inattentive to the details tonight unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply was out of town. In ancestor solution error is `4:173 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ancestor is not a function`. and after some research, I found the solution for How to select an ancestor!!. I am attaching a solution here. Thank you for guiding me in the correct direction. @Eugene Podskal.